# I have troubles with counting the list elements equal to a given value K

Tags: python

I used the command list.count, but it just doesn't work.
Here's the code:

```
import random

a = [random.randint (1, 10) for c in range (20) ]
print (a)

d = int (input ('Input a number') )
a.count(d)

while d in a:
    list.remove (d)
print(a)
```

Comment: You've got to be more specific than "doesn't work".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to remove `d` from `a` so you would do `a.remove(d)` and not `list.remove(d)`

`list` is an object of a class and not an instance of it, the list you are searching for is not `list`, but `a`:

```
import random
a = [random.randint (1, 10) for c in range (20) ]
print (a)
d = int (input ('Input a number') )
# a.count(d) #doesn't do anything
while d in a:
    a.remove(d) #remove d from a
print(a)
```

Comment: You're welcome, always here to answer, if this was an answer to your question, you should check mark it, it could help others.

Answer (score 0):

The count method works properly and if you are asking why still your code isn't working then
Replace `list.remove(d)` with `a.remove(d)`

Print the value of `a.count(d)` to check whether the count method is working.

Comment: count isn't a function, it is a method.

Comment: @XxJames07- Sorry, my bad.

Comment: for more infos goto [`w3school`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_count.asp)'s explanation

Comment: Actually, I do know the difference between a method and a function for a second I did a mistake. Anyway thanks.